# Unable to pass strings in dbgetquery in r. it says invalid identifier

Tags: sql, r, sqlite

When i run this, it says its invalid identifier "RTX" .

```
 gf<-"cyberpunk"
 #input$rat gives a value of string "RTX"
delete<-paste("select * from games where name = ",gf," and graphics = ",input$rat, sep="")
      
      yx<-dbGetQuery(ValidateUser,delete)
      print(yx)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `glue`

```
glue::glue("select * from games where name = '{gf}' and graphics = '{input$rat}'")
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include quotes in the query for all `character` fields, and `paste0` instead of `paste` will avoid unexpected spaces :

```
delete <- paste0("select * from games where name = '",gf,"' and graphics = '",input$rat,"'")

delete
[1] "select * from games where name = 'cyberpunk' and graphics = 'RTX'"
```